# TFS2010 - Correctly setting up Host Header

Tags: reverse-proxy, team-foundation-server

We have a TFS2010 install on a Win2008R2 Server running IIS7.  I've created a host header for TFS and want to use that instead of `machineName:8080`.  I am getting weird behavior from it now.  Every other time I log in I get:

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://web2/tfs. Team Foundation Server Url: http://web2/tfs. Possible reasons for failure include: - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect. - The Team Foundation Server is offline. - The password has expired or is incorrect. Technical information (for administrator): The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

I force a reconnect and voila - there it is.  Also, connecting to the web site rarely works but connecting via VS2010 works 50% of the time.

What do I need to change to stabilize this?

---

> IIS Log File:
>   Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
>   Version: 1.0
>   Date: 2010-05-17 19:47:51
>   Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
>   2010-05-17 19:47:51 192.168.10.240 POST /tfs/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx - 80 - 192.168.10.62 Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe,+10.0.30319.1) 401 2 5 0
>   2010-05-17 19:47:51 192.168.10.240 POST /tfs/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx - 80 MMNT_NET\Keith.Barrows 192.168.10.62 Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe,+10.0.30319.1) 200 0 0 109
>   2010-05-17 19:47:51 192.168.10.240 POST /tfs/RIV/VersionControl/v1.0/repository.asmx - 80 MMNT_NET\Keith.Barrows 192.168.10.62 Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe,+10.0.30319.1) 200 0 0 218
>   Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
>   Version: 1.0
>   Date: 2010-05-17 20:41:50
>   Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
>   2010-05-17 20:41:50 192.168.10.240 POST /tfs/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx - 80 - 192.168.10.62 Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe,+9.0.30729.4413) 401 2 5 78
>   2010-05-17 20:42:11 192.168.10.240 POST /tfs/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx - 80 MMNT_NET\keith.barrows 192.168.10.62 Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe,+9.0.30729.4413) 404 0 0 21466

I am not sure how to interpret it.  Looks like a 404 followed by a 200, or a 401, 404...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the log info.  Try hitting this page directly in a web browser:  /tfs/Services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx. That's throwing a 401.2 which suggests that something is wrong with the configuration.  You can also try browsing to the /tfs/Services/v1.0 folder in IIS7 Manager.  If there is a config error, it should pop up with a message and details on what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks Scott - I'll take a look tomorrow when I have "free time".  :)

Comment: Did the browse to thing and no errors popped up.  It seems like it has its wires crossed.  When I request http://tfs.rivworks.com it tries to deliver http://web2/tfs instead.  It is like the config for TFS is missing some of its own config.

Comment: Any chance the bindings on the site are responding the opposite as you expect?  Like you say, it seems like its wires are crossed.

Comment: Hmmm.  Ran MS TFS Best Practices Analyzer and I have this **warning** popping up:  
> The server bindings for Web site "Team Foundation Server" contains at least one host header string. Check the "Multiple identities" settings under Properties / Web Site / Advanced button, Advanced Web Site Identification.    

I deleted the named binding and reran the analyzer and the warning still pops up!  I think something in the web.config or DB is giving wrong info now...

Comment: Went back into the TFS Admin Console and changed URLs (again).  Made sure it was all pointing to http://web2:8080/tfs.  Needed to refresh twice before the Admin Console actually showed it all.  Now connecting seems to work **except** I'd like a host name connection rather than a machine name connection.  But hey, at least it works again.

Comment: Analyzer view:  http://screencast.com/t/OGU4ZDY5

Comment: TFS Admin view:  http://screencast.com/t/YmE2ZTNkNTI

Comment: Still leaves me wondering how to **correctly** set up a host header for TFS2010!  :)

Comment: It sounds like TFS wants your host headers in IIS to match what it expects.  I bet it depends on WCF which also requires that.  I don't know TFS and how to recommend the configuration, but it sounds like Properties / Web Site / Advanced button is the place to start, then make it match your IIS bindings.  Just make sure that IIS only has exactly 1 binding, and that it's the binding that you want.  That may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For the web2 website, what do the IIS logs give for a status code?  That should be telling as to whether the request makes it as far as the server, and if so, what error is throw from the TFS server.